# How does SQL Group By clause divides query result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table below:

[image]

And when I run this query:

```
Select Gender, City, SUM(Salary) as TotalSalary, COUNT(ID) as [Total Employees]
from tblEmployee 
Group by Gender, City
```

The output table is:

[image]

I am a confused on how from the query is the Total Employees being sorted out. I have `Count(ID) as [Total Employees]` in the Query but how is the Group by clause in the SQL code dividing up the Total Employees? Since I thought `Count(ID) as [Total Employees]` will return 10 since I have 10 records in my table but I am not sure how this group by clause is dividing up the total employees equally? Is it by City or by Gender?

Comment: `Count` and other aggregation functions work with rows in subgroup, not entire table

Comment: GROUP BY clauses provide the aggregate values (in this case COUNT(ID) and SUM(Salary) by the field list other than the aggregates (in this case Gender and City). So you would get TotalEmployees and their total (sum) salaries for each unique combination City and Gender.

Comment: @vmachan That makes complete sense now. Thanks for the concise explanation!

Comment: **The funny thing is that I think you use `SQL Server` and not `Oracle` as your initial tag indicated.** Output looks like grid view from SSMS and `[Total Employees]` is quoting from `SQL Server`. Accepted answer uses doc from `Postgresql`, my answer from `Oracle` and the correct doc should be MSDN. But don't worry GROUP BY and agg functions are standarized things so it will work with specified RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General info about grouping

Taken from Postgres [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html). `GROUP BY` clause behavior is described below.

**Edit**. After reading @lad2025 comment I'm putting some clarification. Yes, explanation of `GROUP BY` clause is quoted from specific DBMS manual, but those things are implemented likewise among all different database vendors I'm familiar with, so it shouldn't matter from which vendor you get the information as long as it's understandable for you.

> The optional **GROUP BY** clause has the general form:
>
> ```
> GROUP BY expression [, ...]
> ```
>
> GROUP BY will condense into a single row all selected rows that share
>   the same values for the grouped expressions.
>
> [...]
>
> Aggregate functions, if any are used, are computed across all rows making up each group, producing a separate value for each group.

## Response to your question

**Question** :

> I am a confused on how from the query is the Total Employees being sorted out. I have Count(ID) as [Total Employees] in the Query but how is the Group by clause in the SQL code dividing up the Total Employees? Since I thought Count(ID) as [Total Employees] will return 10 since I have 10 records in my table but I am not sure how this group by clause is dividing up the total employees equally? Is it by City or by Gender?

**Answer** :

Remember that what name you assign to a column (as alias) doesn't actually impact the behavior and data presented in this column. Your column `TotalEmployees` counts every occurence of column `id` for every group that consists of those columns from the `GROUP BY` clause.

In your particular case each different pair of values from columns `(Gender, City)` is being condensed into exactly one row. Without your `TotalEmployees` column this would behave the same as applying `DISTINCT` to your query, so that **both below presented queries would yield the same result**:

```
1. Select Gender, City from tblEmployee Group by Gender, City;

2. Select Distinct Gender, City from tblEmployee;
```

Going back to your questions, aggregate function `COUNT(*)` (and any aggregate function for that matter) is being applied on **entire grouped expression**. This means that both below queries would yield the same number of `id` column occurence:

```
1. SELECT Count(ID) as [Total Employees] from tblEmployee;

2. SELECT SUM([Total Employees])
FROM (
  SELECT 
    Gender, City, SUM(Salary) as TotalSalary, COUNT(ID) as [Total Employees] 
  FROM 
    tblEmployee 
  GROUP BY Gender, City
  ) foo
```

Answer (score 1):

First SQL separates your table into all the different genders (2), then it separates those groups into all the different cities (3).

2 * 3 = 6, i.e. there are 6 output rows.  However, there are no London females so you get 5 output rows.

The select part of the query - including count(whatevers) - are done per each of the 6 groups.  You can't get total employee count in this query by itself; you have to make a separate query.

Comment: This was very clear and simple to follow. Thank you!

Comment: I find the last part a bit misleading, because if you modify the query you can actually get total employee count which would be visible in each group.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` and other aggregation functions work for rows in group designated by `GROUP BY` clause, not per entire table.

> **[GROUP BY clause](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html)**
>
> **A GROUP BY clause, part of a SelectExpression, groups a result into
>   subsets that have matching values for one or more columns.** In each
>   group, no two rows have the same value for the grouping column or
>   columns. NULLs are considered equivalent for grouping purposes.
>
> **[Aggregate functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035)**
>
> **return a single result row based on groups of
>   rows, rather than on single rows.** Aggregate functions can appear in
>   select lists and in ORDER BY and HAVING clauses. They are commonly
>   used with the GROUP BY clause in a SELECT statement, **where Oracle
>   Database divides the rows of a queried table or view into groups.**

[image]

In your case you make groups based on `Gender` and `City`.

```
           Gender   City        #
Blue:      Male     London      x5
Orange:    Female   New York    x2
Yellow:    Male     New York    x1
Brown:     Male     Sydney      x1
Olive:     Female   Sydney      x1
```

---

To get total `COUNT` per entire table you can use windowed functions with `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Gender,
  City,
  SUM(Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY Gender, City) AS TotalSalary,
  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Gender, City) AS EmployeePerGroup,
  COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalEmployees
FROM tab
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo_Oracle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96e3a/3/0)**</kbd> 
<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo_SQL_Server`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a55cb/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ GENDER  ║   CITY    ║ TOTALSALARY  ║ EMPLOYEEPERGROUP  ║ TOTALEMPLOYEES ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ Male    ║ London    ║       27300  ║                5  ║             10 ║
║ Female  ║ New York  ║        8500  ║                2  ║             10 ║
║ Male    ║ New York  ║        7000  ║                1  ║             10 ║
║ Male    ║ Sydney    ║        2800  ║                1  ║             10 ║
║ Female  ║ Sydney    ║        4800  ║                1  ║             10 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it helped to clarify my problem!